# Некорректное отображение текста

Tags: поддержка

На сайте Русский язык задал вопрос. В вопросе есть перечень со скобками, но после того, как ответ публикуется, скобки изменяются на точки. В чем проблема?

Вот ссылка на вопрос. [В каком ряду не все слова образованы одинаковым способом?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474772/%d0%92-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: Странно... У меня всё нормально отображается.

Comment: @Зонтик, у вас скобки видны или точки?

Comment: Точки! [​](https://google.com)

Comment: @Зонтик, ну да, сейчас точки. Но изначально я ставил скобки, но они меняются на точки.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы была скобка, надо перед скобкой поставить `\`. Правда, тогда не будет автоматических отступов.

Comment: А почему скобки не отображаются,в чем проблема?

Comment: Настроено так, что автоматически превращается в точку. Система американская, может, там не используются скобки.

Comment: Мне почему-то баллы не пришли. Эти голоса не добавляются?

Comment: Надо у модераторов спросить.

Comment: Поставил лайк этому вопросу. Баллы пришли?

Comment: Не знаю. Оповещения не было.

Comment: Ну, список баллов там, где значок кубка.

Comment: Ну да, просто  до голосования не смотрел, сколько было балов, поэтому не знаю. Ну обычно оповещение  приходит.

Comment: Оно должно вверху писать, что +10 за этот вопрос.

Comment: Да, но такого оповещения не было. Странно.